# ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table. After rename Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I got error 1812 on mysql after renaming a primary key. (mysqld 8.0.29 on Centos 7) Please excuse my English.

First I created a table with `id` as the primary key on PHPMyAdmin. Then after some quick consideration I changed it to `code`, as soon as I hit the apply button, I got "tablespace is missing" error. Luckily this table is still empty, but the weird thing is now it said I have ~4,294,967,295 rows in that table.

Now I can not do anything to that specific table, drop or copy or rename or anything because the tablespace is missing. I can't even do mysqldump to the database because of that table.

I searched through stackoverflow, some people got this error after copying the idb files from another machine, I didn't copy it from other machine or databases or any files, all was running normal before this error.

This are what I have tried:

- I tried to dump the db to a file, and got the error "mysqldump: Got error: 1812: Tablespace is missing for table tablename.", even with -f option.
- Another solution suggest to rename/delete the idb file and restart, did that and nothing is changed (i use seperated idb files -- innodb_file_per_table = ON)
- I've Checked the ownership and permission. It is mysql:mysql so I think it's all good.
- Tried the ALTER TABLE tablename DISCARD TABLESPACE; got the "tablespace is missing" running that command.
- Create dummy table and rename the idb to the corrupt table, chown, restart the service, still nothing is changed.
- Create tablespace manually and assigned it to the table, restart the service and nothing change.
- Restart the service, even restarting the server didn't help.
- Tried the "Repair" option on phpmyadmin, [and got this error (tablespace is missing, table not exist, corrupt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH8Sf.png)

My other table on that database is still working normally, and all other databases too. So I can just use another table name and ignore that. But I want that table removed, or at least so I can do mysqldump for backup routine (now I just create a snapshot of the server every day for backup)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like an error in the filesystem unrelated to the structure change occures during this operation. Recommendations: discard tablespace, drop table, delete errorneous files, recreate table.